# SwiftStock build error Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, stock

I am trying to use SwiftStock (https://github.com/ackleymi/SwiftStock) for a project but i am having a problem i can't find a solution for.
I keep running into an error when i try to run the Exemple project on the Github:
"Linked command failed with exit code 1".
When I double click on it I get a more precise error:
**ld: framework not found Pods_SwiftStockExample
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I installed correctly Cocoapods (pod install) and it ran without any error.
I tried different solution found on Stackoverflow:
- Going to "Edit Scheme"->Build and unsetting "Tests"
- Going to the projects configurations and settings "Debug" and "Release" to None

But nothing seems to work.

Has anyone ever had such an error?

Thank you!

Comment: sounds like you might be opening the project file instead of the .xcworkspace file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a podfile and run install, it generates a new workspace file in the same folder where your project file is.

The workspace file maintains the dependency of different frameworks referring each other and that is why it is required to open the workspace file if you have pods install instead of the project file.

Go find youProject.workspace file and open it. Compile it and every thing should be fine.

Comment: thanks a lot. that fixed it !! as usual, not that hard... :)